# SQLite sendo acessado pelo GCM

Tags: android, sqlite

Eu preciso que o meu GCM, quando receber uma mensagem, salve no banco de dados as informações, porém fica dando erro, deve ser porque a aplicação não está aberta. Alguém sabe o que devo fazer?
Tenho o seguinte método dentro do meu CommonUtilities do GCM:

```
public static void SaveDatabase(int remetente, int destinatario, String msg, Context context){
     try{

      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

      ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
      values.put(DbHelper.C_REMETENTE, remetente);
      values.put(DbHelper.C_DESTINATARIO, destinatario);
      values.put(DbHelper.C_MSG, msg);
      try{
        db.insertOrThrow(DbHelper.TABLE, null, values);
      }finally
      {
        db.close();
      }
      GCMIntentService.generateNotification(context, "SALVOU");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        GCMIntentService.generateNotification(context, "ERRO: " + e.toString());
        //GCMIntentService.generateNotification(context, e.getMessage());
      //Log.e("error sqlite", e.getMessage());
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Gabriel, não faz muito sentido dar erro, a aplicação está sim aberta. O que não está aberta é a `Activity` (Dê uma olhada no conceito de `Task` e `TaskStack`). Se puder coloque o stacktrace do erro.

Comment: Então cara como tá no try catch não me mostra o erro, eu imprimi o a execução e e ele da o erro null,  achei muito estranho, lembrando que essa função é a mesma que está funcionando em outra classe apenas copiei e colei, então o erro não é o código.

Comment: Dê um `e.printStackTrace` pra sair o stacktrace no log.

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.